# Date labels and partition line are getting overlaid

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add play/pause + slider functionality to the below-working code:

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/f2b02646a6c72a99789371079d188f0f

So far I have managed to add that functionality but the thing is my date info on the right side is not getting updated and also the vertical lines are getting added up.

This is what I have done:
https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/2b6fcd7607b510f0c0b6467e663ff764

I am using the same code. I don't know what's causing this problem? and how to solve this.

**Edit:**

That date thing is fixed now.

```
  yearText.html(sDate.toDateString());
```

I was using `sDate` (starting Date) not the current one.

**Edit2:**

This is the problem:

[image]

They are getting overlaid.

Comment: I don't get it, your second link shows the date field updating above the slider. Where else is the date being shown? Could you screenshot and show exactly what is not updating?

Comment: Sat Mar 14 2020 <-- this thing I was talking about. Leave that date thing I am facing that vertical lines problems right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the following lines of code in your `drawplot(data)` function which updates every time the slider moves. It is appending the tick marks everytime. Comment out the following code:

```
//      svg.append('g')
//        .attr('class', 'axis xAxis')
//        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${margin.top})`)
//        .call(xAxis)
//        .selectAll('.tick line')
//        .classed('origin', d => d == 0);
```

The same thing is happening with your `yearText` everytime you are using `drawplot`, instead of updating the date, it appends new dates.

The append for all of these should be outside the `drawplot` or to separate the updates to a different function.

Comment: But this will not give me anything initially. when I use slider then it will show me date and those lines. How should I fixed that?

Comment: Like append only once and modify the value.

Comment: For date thing I can't do this as it will give me errors.

Comment: I solved it but now I get some different error. I will close this one and ask a new question.

Comment: Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001976/getting-some-weird-bar-which-is-not-part-of-my-data