# Getting some weird bar which is not part of my data

Tags: d3.js

This is the follow up question of [Date labels and partition line are getting overlaid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941046/date-labels-and-partition-line-are-getting-overlaid/61941503#61941503)

Now It is solved. My date and vertical tick line is getting updated but the problem is I get this weird bar and number see that "2" in the left side:

[image]

I am getting this green bar named state unassigned. I don't why I am getting this. Below kashmir you can see there is a number "2" (another bar it seems with value 2).

So you can see I am getting this for month April So when I use the slider to reproduce it. It's gone. 
I don't get these things when I use slider but when I do autoplay then this issue occurs.

I don't know how to solve for this one issue.

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/d76a0d397851a03a9fc203411880eba9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from the data API side. They have added some elements after some dates. That's why this occurred.